# ZF2: ZFTool error i cannot find the autoloader of the application

Tags: zend-framework2

When i run: php zf.php

Error I cannot find the autoloader of the application
Check if ...\ZFTool contains a valid ZF2 application

Help me, thank all

Comment: Try using the `zftool.phar` file instead. Refer this http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html to create the `.phar` file and execute it from `module` folder. You will need to take care with the path to the file. Eg: in module folder - `php ../vendor/ZFTool/zftool.phar`

Comment: For `autoloader` error, the `zf.php ...` command should be from within project folder. Only then the `autoloader` file can be found. So the path will be `php vendor/ZFTool/zf.php ...`

Answer (score 0):

> you need to access zf.php file from your application root directory
>   only then only it will find autoloader of the application

**step1:** locate your zf-application folder from command line.
eg. cd D:\xampp\htdocs\ZF2-Demo
(Note: do not go under **vendor\ZFTool** you need to locate only application root directory.)

**step2:** type **php vendor/ZFTool/zf.php**